# How to send json results to an email when button is pressed in swift 4?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am coming to a problem where I have a list of json question where when the user fills out the general questions, I show the a button to submit and all I want to do is make that submit button to send me the json results to my email. is it possible with my code? thank you so much! By the way, I am using SurveyNative for survey creation.

```
import UIKit
import SurveyNative

class MyViewController: SurveyViewController, SurveyAnswerDelegate, CustomConditionDelegate, ValidationFailedDelegate {



   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      self.setSurveyAnswerDelegate(self)
      self.setCustomConditionDelegate(self)
      self.setValidationFailedDelegate(self)

    }


  override func surveyJsonFile() -> String {
      return "GeneralQuestions"
   }

   override func surveyTitle() -> String {
      return "General Questions"
   }




   func question(for id: String, answer: Any) {
      print("Question: \(id) has answer (maybe is complete): \(answer)")
      if (surveyQuestions!.isQuestionFullyAnswered(id)) {
          print("Question: \(id) is complete")
      }
   }

   func isConditionMet(answers: [String: Any], extra: [String: Any]?) -> Bool {
      let id = extra!["id"] as! String
      if id == "check_age" {
         if let birthYearStr = answers["birthyear"] as? String, let ageStr = answers["age"] as? String {
            let birthYear = Int(birthYearStr)
            let age = Int(ageStr)
            let wiggleRoom = extra!["wiggle_room"] as? Int
            let date = Date()
            let calendar = Calendar.current
            let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year], from: date)
            let currentYear =  components.year
            return abs(birthYear! + age! - currentYear!) > wiggleRoom!
         } else {
            return false
         }
      } else {
         Logger.log("Unknown custom condition check: \(id)")
         return false
      }
   }

   func validationFailed(message: String) {
      let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
      alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
      self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }






}
```

My Json:

```
{
        "questions": [
            {
                "id": "ice_cream",
                "header": "Question 1",
                "question": "Did you enjoy the discussion topic?",
                "question_type": "single_select",
                "options": [
                    "YES",
                    "NO",
                    "I DONT KNOW",

                    {
                        "title": "Other",
                        "type": "freeform"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "perfect_day",
                "header": "Question 2",
                "question": "Did you enjoy the presenter? If yes, why?",
                "question_type": "single_select",
                "options": [
                    "YES",
                    "NO",
                    "I DONT KNOW",

                    {
                        "title": "Other",
                        "type": "freeform"
                    }
                ]
            },



            {
                "id": "ice_cream",
                "header": "Question 3",
                "question": "Did you feel you engaged or connected to the topic discussed?",
                "question_type": "single_select",
                "options": [
                    "YES",
                    "NO",

                    {
                        "title": "Other",
                        "type": "freeform"
                    }
                ]
            },

            {
                "id": "perfect_day",
                "header": "Question 4",
                "question": "Do you have any topics you would like to discuss?",
                "question_type": "single_select",
                "options": [
                    "YES",
                    "NO",
                    "I DONT KNOW",
                ]
            },


            {
                "id": "felt_like_adult",
                "header": "Question 5",
                "question": "Do you feel we can change anything?",
                "question_type": "single_select",
                "options": [
                    "YES",
                    "NO",
                    "I DONT KNOW",

                ]
            },



            {
                "id": "pets",
                "header": "Question 6",
                "question": "Do you prefer a specific presenter? If yes, why?",
                "question_type": "single_select",
                "options": [
                    "YES",
                    "NO",
                    "I DONT KNOW",

                   {
                        "title": "Other",
                        "type": "freeform"
                    }

                ]

            },
        ],
        "submit": {
            "button_title": "Submit Answers",
            "url": "https://www.example.com"
        },
        "auto_focus_text": true
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can I know what's the purpose of getting JSON Results in Email? These are a few option of sending email stated as below.

### Option 1

You can use MFMailComposeViewController to send email from your app. Set your JSON into message body.
Here's [a link](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-send-an-email) about how to send an email with MFMailComposeViewController.

### Option 2

Use API service to send email messages back to your email. For example: Gmail API. You can have a look on [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/)

### Option 3

Create your own API to post the JSON result to your server and receive your message using your own mail server.